# Outlook 2010 Custom Form Distribution

Tags: vba, forms, outlook, outlook-2010

I have just created my fist Custom Appointment/Meeting form and published it to my personal folder so that I can use it, this all works fine.  What I need to do is attach this form to someone else's PC/Mail account and then later this will become a company wide form.  I am struggling trying to export the form and how to get it loaded on someone else's machine and then how to make it a company wide form so that everyone can use it, can anyone help with this?

Thanks P

Answer (score 0):

Publish to the Organizational Forms Library

[How to: Save and Distribute a Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862515%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

"Forms saved in this library are accessible to everyone in your organization and are stored on the server. You must have write permission to save to the server. For more information, see your administrator. Use this library when you want to make the form available to everyone in your organization, such as a form to report vacation time. Saving to this library provides a quick and easy way to distribute and update forms."